# How do you remove a lot of wall tiles?

Tags: tile, demolition

How do I quickly remove a lot of wall tiles without damaging the wall?

Comment: What kind of tiles, and how big are they?

Answer (score 5):

I tried the screwdriver and chisel technique with some tiles in a flat in Brighton... and quickly gave up once I found there were three layers of tiles there! So I invested in a cheapish power chisel - like a hammer drill, only it doesn't go around - and finished the job in a weekend.

If you go this route, it's definitely worth buying ear defenders and a good strong set of goggles as tile chips are sharp. I used my chainsaw helmet and got a couple of dings in it.

Answer (score 2):

Typically I hit the first one (kind of gently) with a hammer until it cracks/shatters.  Grind out the grout then pry out the pieces with a chisel or just a beefy flathead screwdriver.

Once you have one out, you should be able to use a chisel or a flat head screwdriver to get under the other ones.  Put the screwdriver under/against the edge of the tile and tap it with a hammer and the tiles will (usually) just pop off.  Some will be more stubborn than others, but if you're reasonably careful you shouldn't damage the wall much.

Answer (score 0):

I used a small crowbar and sometimes a hammer. The backing was failing, so it was painfully easy to ram the bar down and separate the tile. The task took me less than an hour, undoubtedly aided by the failing backing.

Per previous comment, protective equipment is a must. I used ear-protection, eye-protection and a dust-mask.

UPDATE: Since my first answer, I had to do another room for someone else. I used a small pneumatic hammer with 3" shovel bit (chisel). I used the hammer in my right hand and a putty-knife in my left (to keep the chisel off the cement-board), and this allowed me to move VERY quickly. Even though I was wearing a full-face breathing apparatus, my forehead got several small cuts because the air-hammer shatters so much of the tile. If that's a concern, I'd stick with a small crowbar / flatbar (the same I'd use for removing wood trim from walls).